# Visual Studio Projects or Labs? Where?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have seen several online tutorials learning VS 2005, 2008 and 2010. But after you have learned all the basics, where can you start with some labs. Sure you could start creating stuff on your own; but what about some actual projects? Like "1001 Visual Studio Projects/Labs for the week-end" - Am I wishing to much?

Comment: And you would like to browse through all of them... Just pick yourself something you would like to do and go for it... when you get stuck check for the solution and carry on... that's the best way... learning by doing (not watching and rewriting)

Answer (score 0):

When you open Visual Studio it displays the start page.

There you have several tabs. in the 'Get Started' tab Check the inner tab called Windows or Web given your preference.

If you're a beginner check the link available in the start page RSS feed
http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C-Sharp-Fundamentals-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners

If you're interested, for instance in WPF, google e.g. "WPF tutorial" or consider reading a book on the subject.

Happy coding.

Comment: I’m going to add more this. Years ago you could get project kits in Electronics.. parts connected by springs and such. You could spend the week-end building and tinkering. That’s what I’m seeking.

Comment: @user1206919: try googling hands-on labs c#